# Left join en NoSQL MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Estoy tratando de obtener solo los **proyectos cuyos empleados sean hombres**,

Mis **Schemas** son los siguientes:

**Proyectos** por un lado:

```
        projects: {
            project: {
                _id: ObjectId('xxxx'),
                project_name: String('Project A'),
                project_employees: [{
                    0: ObjectId('AAAA'),
                    1: ObjectId('BBBB')
                }]
            }
        }
```

**Empleados por otro:**

```
         employees: {
            employee: {
                _id: ObjectId('AAAA'),
                employee_firstname: String("Jane Doe"),
                employee_gender: String("female")
            },
            employee: {
                _id: ObjectId('BBBB'),
                employee_firstname: String("John Doe"),
                employee_gender: String("male")
            }
        }
```

Primero lo he intentado con **populate()**, pero los **match** solo afectan a los sub-documentos, y luego he intentado usar **$lookup** (Aggregation).

Aquí el código:

```
        Project.aggregate([{
            $lookup: {
                from: "employees",
                let: { employees_in: "$project_employees" },
                pipeline: [{
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                             $and: [{ $eq: ["$_id", "$$employees_in"] },
                                   { $eq: ["$employee_gender", "male"] },
                              ]
                        }
                    }
                }],
                as: 'employees'
            }
        }], (err, projects) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error 500' });
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({ projects });
            }
        });
```

No consigo que me devuelva lo que necesito, a ver si alguien tiene alguna idea, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Tu solución es correcta pero ten en cuenta de que te traerías a todos los usuarios que estén vinculados con el proyecto en cuestión, ya sean `male` o `female`, por lo que estarías trabajando con mas datos de los necesarios ya que aunque realices el `$match` en la siguiente etapa solo te filtraría los documentos que no contenga en el Array de documentos `$project_employees` un documento con el campo `employee_gender` distinto a `male`.

Te propongo una solución mas efectiva si tu proyecto lo acepta.

En vez de comenzar la relación con la colección `Project`, porque no empiezas con `Employess`, así filtrarías antes de realizar el `$lookup`, reduciendo el numero de documentos a relacionar. Te pongo la query:

```
Employees.aggregate([{
      $match: {
         "employee_gender" : "male"
      }
   },{
      $lookup:{
          from: "projects",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "project_employees",
          as: "projects"
        }
   }]);
```

Una cosa más, aprovecho para comentarte una cosa sobre tu query que es posible que no te este dando los resultados esperados:

```
    Project.aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
            from: "employees",
            let: { employees_in: "$project_employees" },
            pipeline: [{
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                         $and: [{ $in: ["$_id", "$$employees_in"] }, //Al ser un Array necesitas utilizar el operador $in en vez de $eq
                               { $eq: ["$employee_gender", "male"] },
                          ]
                    }
                }
            }],
            as: 'employees'
        }
    }], (err, projects) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error 500' });
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({ projects });
        }
    });
```

Aunque hayas solucionado tu problema espero que este punto de vista te ayude a tu proyecto.

Un saludo

Comment: ¡Buen planteamiento! Gracias, aún me queda por aprender.

Answer (score 0):

Tras unos días he hallado la solución, simplemente puedo hacer el **$match** después del **$lookup** y utilizar la variable **$project_employees** para hacer el filtro del género.

```
 Project.aggregate([{
$lookup:
  {
    from: "employees",
    localField: "project_employees",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "project_employees"
  },
  {$match: {
    "$project_employees.employee_gender" : "male"
  }
}}]);
```

más información aquí: [Documentación MongoBD $lookup (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que hagas la relacion entre colecciones al reves,

```js
employee: {
  ...
  projectId: ObjectId("...")
}
```

en vez de

```js
project: {
  employeeIds: [
    ObjectId("...")
  ]
}
```

y despues haces el lookup pero al reves.

Tené en cuenta que un documento de MongoDB tiene un límite de tamaño permitido